# Is it possible for a DAG to wait for the previous scheduled DAG to finish

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a scenario where my DAG's run on weekdays. Once every day from Mon to Fri.
I want the DAG to wait for the previous scheduled run to complete. ie Mondays run should not execute (should wait at first task) untill Fridays DAG run is complete.
I tried using task sensor, but I am finding it difficult to pass the timedelta with day=2 for the field execution_delta.
Any pointers?

Inside dag d1-

```
ExternalTaskSensor(
task_id='t1',external_dag_id='d1',allowed_states=['success'],execution_delta= timedelta(days=1)
)
```

This works if I don't consider weekends

I tried depends_on_past and wait_for_downstrean and catchup flags. This does not help entirely.